# how to generically get all .o files for ar

Tags: c++, makefile

I have a source tree with some **subfolders\sub-units**. There is a **makefile** in each **subfolder**. The object files will create by these **subfolder makefile** and the object files will be put in a **obj folder** in the top level by them.

The **makefile** in the top level will generate a **.a file** from all the available object files in that **obj folder**.

I am thinking to minimize the changes when new cpp files are added by let top level **makefile** **automatically** figure out all object files in that obj folder.

I have tried the following but no luck:

```
OBJ_LIST=$(wildcard ${OBJ_DIR}/*.o)
```

Anybody can help me?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the Makefile i use to generate a *.a file

```
NAME    = zzz.a

SRC     = xxx.c \
          yyy.c

OBJ     = $(SRC:.c=.o)

CC      = gcc

CFLAGS  = -W -Wall -Wextra -O2

RM      = rm -f

all:    $(NAME)

$(NAME):        $(OBJ)
                ar rc $(NAME) $(OBJ)
                ranlib $(NAME)

clean:
            $(RM) $(OBJ)

fclean:
            $(RM) $(OBJ) $(NAME)

re:             fclean all

.PHONY: all clean fclean re
```

$(SRC:.c=.o) is used manipulate all *.o file contained in the project